# Which version of VB does MS Access use?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Which version of VB does MS Access use in the code editor?  Is it VBA, VB.Net, other? I sometimes get confused when searching for help/solutions. For instance, in Access, you can't do:

```
Dim s as String = "hello"
```

But you can do:

```
Dim s
s = "hello"
```

Comment: Which version of Access?

Comment: All version of Access from 2003 to 2010 use Visual Basic for Applications v6.x - I'm not certain about Access 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Microsoft Office applications use VBA.  Excel, Access, Word, Outlook, and Powerpoint can be scripted using VBA.  There are ways to extend this to shell scripting, ActiveX, etc and, by extension, a good number of other languages that those extensions can tap you into.  I embed SQL into Excel VBA macros.

VB has a slightly different syntax and a different IDE.